# Moving an Image while Scrolling (Javascript)

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, animation

I want to move a picture while scrolling to a fixed position and I want to move the picture when I scrolled down like 800px.

My problem here is that when I scroll down the image is moving but on its way down it flickers and also does this when I scroll up.

Javascript:

```
    if ($(window).width() >= 1024) {

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 800){
              $('.Pic_mv').each(function (i) {
                $(this).toggleClass('scrolled');
            });
        }else if ($(window).scrollTop <= 800){
               $('.Pic_mv').each(function (i) {
                $(this).toggleClass('.Pic_mv');
            });
        }  
    }) ;
}
```

CSS:

```
  .Pic_mv {
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;

    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;

}
.Pic_mv.scrolled {
     transform: translate(85%, 1300px)  ;

}
```

How can i achive a smooth animation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand truly, You want to fix the image as you reach 800px scrolling from top. I did not use any kind of animation, just classadd and remove. The problem of your code I belive is; You are not giving display:fixed property on your .scrolled class.

Check out the link [**Here**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=aaa42abb0ba27f60f8fc550fe4d32f02) and tell me what is exactly you trying to get if I missunderstand.

Comment: As the user reaches 800px on scrolling down i want to move the picture to a  other fixed position and when the useres scroll up > 800 px the picture should go on its position where i was before

Comment: What is the 'other fixed position'? Exactly where? I checked out your example and generate one from there but if you want to move it some exact position give me details.